# need help for inline the button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSxab.png)

```html
<td style="text-align:center">
  <button type="button" style="display:inline-block; background-color: #4CAF50;">Accept</button>
  <button type="button" style="display:inline-block;background-color: #f44336; ">Reject</button>
</td>
```

I was doing a table right now .for the action field I want to inline to two button but it didn't inline properly. Hope somebody helps. thankyou in advance

Comment: Can you provide image samples? Also, it would be better if you write a better title for the question, as "needing help" may be implicit in this site ;). "buttons not aligned", perhaps?

Comment: hello i have already update an images. also thankyou for your suggestion. :)

Comment: yes . i am using bootstrap

Comment: You need to adjust the width of the TD. Or use style white-space: nowrap; for td. But be cautious, it can change the width of other TDs and may be you don't want this should happen.

Comment: @shyam thankyou! the white-space: nowrap; was working!

Answer (score 0):

increase your td width . its causing the buttons to behave like a block .
your css is fine !